# How can I change the default 'Related To'

Tags: tasks

The defautl 'Related To' list on a new task defaults to 'Accounts...'

[image]

Is it possible, that the 'Related To' will default to 'Opportunity'? how can I select that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible.

Kindly do vote on the below Idea link.

[Related To Default](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrBvAAK)

Comment: sheesh - a meritorious idea 12 years old still unenacted